# Converting from formula to clause

Tags: propositional-calculus

I'm trying to refresh myself on the subject.

If φ= (L1 ∨...∨ Ln) whereL1,...,Ln are literals, then{L1, ..., Ln}is the clause associated to φ.

How would I convert ¬(¬P ∨ Q) to a clause?

Answer (score 1):

To convert to clauses, you first need to put your expression into CNF:

$\neg (\neg P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg \neg P \land \neg Q \Leftrightarrow P \land \neg Q$

Now that it is in CNF, you know that each conjunct is a generalized disjunction that can be made into a clause. In this case, you have two conjuncts, so you will get two clauses: $\{ P \}$ and $\{ \neg Q \}$